# Problem after installing xorg-dev

Tags: installation, boot, xorg

I install xorg by the following command: (I need `X11` to work with *Heasoft*)

```
sudo apt-get -y install xorg-dev
```

After I reboot the black screen appears and is written:

```
Could not write bytes: Broken pipe
```

I can't proceed  afterwards, and ubuntu does not start. Only this black screen stays.

This is the only thing I do. Maybe having windows along with ubuntu has some influence? I just installed ubuntu on part of `D:` disc on free space, following the instructions. Giving 500MB for swap and the left free space as `ext4`
Please help I really need ubuntu first of all for installing this software that uses x11.

---

I have installed Ubuntu 12.03LTS on windows 7, on disc partition.

Comment: Can you give us the exact command you are running and the whole error message? Please hit "edit" on the question and add the information. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 12.04, you need to install `xserver-xorg-dev-lts-raring` (or `-lts-saucy` if it's the case) before installing `xorg-dev`. The `-lts` packages are part of the [Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#LTS_Enablement_Stacks). If you try to install `xorg-dev` directly, it will remove some of them.